# Wildcard inside an "if" statement?

Tags: stata

I have a list of variables ending in similar manner:

```
variable_1_2
variable_1_3
variable_1_4
variable_2_2
variable_2_3
```

etc.

I would like to define a variable based on the value of **all** of these variables. If any of them are 0, I would like my new variable to also be 0 as such:

```
gen newVar = .
replace newVar = 0 if variable_* == 0
```

However this returns "invalid name".

Can wildcard not be used inside an if statement? Is there a way around this?

Comment: So you want the newvariable to be 0 if any argument is 0, and missing otherwise? The best method will depend on what else is going on. Various functions of `egen` will loop for you. (Indicators that are 1 or 0 are very much more useful than those that are 0 or missing -- or 1 or missing.)

Comment: So if variable_1_1 == 1 and variable_1_2 == 0 then I want newVar == 0. I intend to run the same command but then with 1 instead of 0 which will overlap the 0's that were "true" 1's, leaving only the 0's that had all as 0 left, as many of the variables are also missing so it's maybe a kind of a junk solution but it usually works.

Comment: To answer your underlying question, wildcards are not allowed in `if` qualifiers (the case here) or `if` statements. Apart from being unsupported and so illegal, there is an open question of why one might expect the "any" interpretation rather than the "all" interpretation of the syntax you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of

```
generate wanted = .  

foreach v of var variable_* {  
    replace wanted = 0 if `v' == 0 
}
```

will be 0 if any argument is 0 and missing otherwise.

```
egen anyzero = anymatch(variable_*), values(0)
```

will produce an indicator that is 1 if any argument is 0 and 0 if no arguments are. You can always flip 0 and 1 as results if you need the complement.